# Isotop vertical tabs need to show first item on loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I have used Isotop JS to filter and show my contents in vertical tabs. Here I just edited the style like to show single item under a tab. Now there is a **problem**: when the initial loading of page it shows all content inside the tabs. Actually **i need to show only first item content when the first loading.**

Here is my code:

```js
// Loads Isotope
$('#items').isotope();

// Filters out items
$('#filters a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $('#items').isotope({
    filter: selector
  });
});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.isotop-tabs {
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.isotop-tabs li {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.isotop-tabs li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/3.0.4/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div id="isotope">

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <ul class="isotop-tabs" id="filters">
      <li><a href="#" data-filter=".one">Item one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-filter=".two">Item two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-filter=".three">Item three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-filter=".four">Item four</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-filter=".five">Item five</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div id="items" class="item-list">
      <div class="item one">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/555x150" class="img-responsive">
        <h3>Heading One</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item two">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/555x150" class="img-responsive">
        <h3>Heading Two</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item three">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/555x150" class="img-responsive">
        <h3>Heading Three</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item four">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/555x150" class="img-responsive">
        <h3>Heading Four</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item five">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/555x150" class="img-responsive">
        <h3>Heading Five</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Also JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vishnuprasadps/c0kf8nyf/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add new `isotope()` at begginning passing the first item as a selector:

```js
var first = $(".item:first")
$('#items').isotope({
    filter: first
});

// Filters out items
$('#filters a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $('#items').isotope({
        filter: selector
    });
});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.isotop-tabs {
  border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
}

.isotop-tabs li {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.isotop-tabs li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/3.0.4/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div id="isotope">

  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <ul class="isotop-tabs" id="filters">
      <li><a href="#" data-filter=".one">Item one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-filter=".two">Item two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-filter=".three">Item three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-filter=".four">Item four</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-filter=".five">Item five</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div id="items" class="item-list">
      <div class="item one">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/555x150" class="img-responsive">
        <h3>Heading One</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item two">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/555x150" class="img-responsive">
        <h3>Heading Two</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item three">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/555x150" class="img-responsive">
        <h3>Heading Three</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item four">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/555x150" class="img-responsive">
        <h3>Heading Four</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item five">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.co//i/555x150" class="img-responsive">
        <h3>Heading Five</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Nice..! but still all contents shows for a few seconds at the time of loading.

Comment: Yes.. Fine now. I think it may takes a bit of time to load all contents.

Comment: Glad to help you